# Ansible large file storage

Tags: git, ansible

I have a question more about best practices as we switch from a pilot to production use of Ansible.  We are using Ansible to install products and patches that are not available in yum or some other repo.  They arrive as zip files ranging up to 600MB and we push them to the servers as zip files and unpack them there.  This all works fine.  We have historically stored those zips in the project’s files/products and files/patches directories.

We are now migrating our project to Git (Bitbucket).  Many would say you shouldn’t store the binaries in Git.  When trying, we’ve had limited success committing and pushing the larger files (we get timeouts).  If we just store them on the server in the project directory one has to be very careful not to enable the “Delete on Update” setting in the project as it will blow away a substantial library of products and patches when the project updates.  It feels a bit precarious.

With this understanding, how are others storing large files and distributing them using Ansible?  Are they stored external to the project and referenced using fully qualified paths?  Have you implemented some other form of repo for these large files that Ansible can fetch them from?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you really, really do not want to be storing binaries in Git. It's going to make it an absolute nightmare for you to easily clone the repo (both for development as well as deployment) and navigate the project.

If you have some large binary that you have to deploy using Ansible then that binary belongs in some form of binary or artifact repository. In our case we use [Aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) for storing snapshots of apt repos and [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) for general binaries (normally zip files but also occasionally WAR files and lots of other stuff too).

In the case of Aptly we simply point at that as if it was a normal apt repo and in the case of Artifactory we use Ansible's [`get_url`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.html) module to download the binaries from the central Artifactory server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a few reasons that storing large files in Git isn't recommended, including that every developer has to keep every copy of those files in their checkout for all time.  You can find a variety of approaches to mitigate this [with a simple web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=git+large+files&ia=web).

As far as Ansible is concerned, this shouldn't change much.  If you use a solution that retains the source files on the machine where you're running Ansible, then you can continue to copy them across as before.

Alternatively, many people store those files on a separate file store (for instance, S3 or a local fileserver) and have the Ansible rules reference remote urls to download those files from the server.  This saves you from having to download them on your local machine, and the primary bandwidth usage is between your servers and the fileserver, rather than your servers and your local machine (which probably isn't tuned to do this).  HTTP(S) is also much more efficient for transferring files than SSH.

With any of these external systems, you'll want to ensure that old versions of the packages are still available when you check out a version of the Ansible code that expects the old version.  Some of the git solutions will handle this automatically, but you can also do it yourself by including a version number or checksum in the filepath.